# Feeds and podcasts for the vim text editor

Tags: vim, feed, podcast

[Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org) is fantastic, and I want more educational, vim-related feeds and podcasts but am having trouble finding any more quality ones. There must be more out there.

Are there other vim-related XML feeds and podcasts?

Comment: +1 This is going to be useful for me too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Derek Wyatt's blog](http://www.derekwyatt.org/category/vim/) is a great resource also.

Comment: Although I was aware of both Vimcasts and Derek Wyatt's blog, I think that these resources are the collective answer. In as much Internet research that I have done on this topic over the past month, I just don't think there is anything else out there of equivalent quality! It should also be noted that Derek Wyatt has recently added some new videos, after something like a year of dormancy! :)

Answer (score 3):

Vim on Reddit http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered a few good ones here: http://lococast.net/?s=vim

Answer (score 0):

I've subscribed to the vim official scripts page RSS :
http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php

But the best source for me these last weeks have been [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I discover a lot of interesting articles via the `#vim` hashtag on Twitter:

http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23vim

There's a lot of noise and duplication, but it's easy to skip over that and get to the good stuff.